# How can I execute try block statements in test case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

How can I execute try block statements in test case? My test case always goes to catch block.

I need to mock question bean, PostingResult, Question, dao all? I am confused. How I can test if/else ? Question class two fields are enums.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/questionservice")
public class QuestionServiceController {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(QuestionServiceController.class);
    private final static Long SUCCESS = 000l;
    private final static Long FAILURE = 999l;

    @Autowired
    QuestionAnswerDao questionAnswerDao;
    @Autowired
    QuestionAnswerDirectoryDao questionAnswerDirectoryDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/postquestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody PostingResult postQuestion(@RequestBody QuestionBean questionBean) {
        System.out.println("In....");
        PostingResult response = new PostingResult();
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("QuestionBean: " + questionBean);
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("in try");
            Question question = questionAnswerDao.postQuestion(getQuestion(questionBean));
            System.out.println("question"+question);
            if (null != question) {
                response.setStatus(SUCCESS);
                response.setStatusMessage("Successfully saved..");
            } else {
                response.setStatusMessage("Question is null..");
                response.setStatus(FAILURE);
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            if (log.isErrorEnabled()) {
                log.error("Exception in processing " + questionBean + "; Exception: " + exp.toString());
            }
            response.setStatusMessage("Saving failed.. Exception: " + exp.toString());
            response.setStatus(FAILURE);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to mock `questionAnswerDao`. Then tell Mockito to throw an exception when `postQuestion()` is invoked.

```
when(questionAnswerDao.postQuestion(/* specify args here */))
    .thenThrow(new SomeException());
```

Then you can test the `response` object to see if it has the right messages and status.

Comment: so what about if/else condition? i should not go for that?

Comment: @ripu You could also test that, by returning null from your mocked object.

Comment: I am not able to enter into if/else condition. @Mock
 QuestionAnswerDao questionAnswerDao=new QuestionAnswerDaoImpl();Mockito.when(questionAnswerDao.postQuestion(question)).thenReturn(null); this is always returning NPE. and thus catch() block is executing. please help.

Comment: @ripu I would post that as a separate question. Include your attempted test code and the relevant code (only) from this question. Please post a link to that question as a comment here, if you don't mind.

Comment: Hi dunacan, I have tested successfully. thanks for the help. :)